# What is a clean and simple method of backing up Ruby on Rails app and MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I started learning Ruby and Rails over the past week or so.  I have completely destroyed my app and had to redo everything a couple of times. haha
It is a giant pain rebuilding everything using only a backup folder of some copied files.  I'm sure I'll break some more stuff in the future.
Are there any good gems or tools that will help me backup both the App and the MySQL database? 
I have used this option for MySQL but it doesn't seem to work well when working with Rails:

```
mysqldump database_name > database_name.sql
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not working well with rails?

Comment: For app code, use git and remote server (github, for example). For database, set up periodic backups (which also copy data dumps to a remote storage)

Comment: In short: there's no "clean and simple way".

Comment: Using any version control system (SVN, git, mercurial, ...) is much easier than having to find bugs without any information about what changed in the meantime. Also, mysqldump should work just fine.

Comment: i bet I'm not using mysqldump correctly.  I'll read up on it more.

Comment: They way I do it is to create a git repo for every project. When I work on a new feature, I create a branch and work on that branch until it works. If it breaks, I delete that branch and start from where I started the branch. If it worked, I merge my branches and tackle the next feature.

Comment: You might want to consider the `--single-transaction` option to get a consistent snapshot, plus `--hex-blob` to avoid having illegible binary files. As you discover options that work well, make a small shell script to properly execute them and archive your database to a file. `| gzip -9 > db.sql.gz` also helps keep file-sizes down.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you don't need to do backup  of your application. You should use version control system (git, for example) and automated deployment (capistrano, chef or whatever). Using this two principles you can always redeploy your application on the broken VPS or transfer it to another server.

Then, about DB backup - just do it using your DB abilities (mysqldump in your case) :) You can set up, for example, CRON task, which will backup your database once a day. But don't forget that it will be much better if you will store your dump on the other server - in case of your server being completely broken.